# GCP - Google cloud platform: Is there any way to push code from eclipse to cloud without any version control system?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to GCP and was exploring some features and need to find a way to push local files to GCP path without any version control.

I know following way to push the code to GCP:

1) using gsutil cp command copy local file changes to GCP bucket.
Eg: gsutil -m cp -r sourcepath gs://bucket-id

2) Copy code from GCP bucket to desired path.
Eg: gsutil cp -r gs://bucket-id/xyz /path

Is there any alternative way to achieve this using eclipse? to transfer files directly from local system to GCP path. Or do we have any eclipse plugin to achieve the same?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to copy the files directly to the gcloud shell directory?

If it is for a backup the bucket is already the best tool for that. if it is for deployment you can already use the App Engine Standard [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploying) from eclipse.